# How to simulate windows keyboard text selection

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, selection

I am attempting to duplicate the way windows selects text via combinations of the shift control and arrow keys.

My current attempt, assume grid is essentially a text box.

```
        Dim selectionStart As Integer = grid.ActiveCell.SelStart
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
            If Not e.Shift Then
                grid.ActiveCell.SelStart = selectionStart + 1
                grid.ActiveCell.SelLength = 0
            Else
                grid.ActiveCell.SelLength += 1
                'grid.ActiveCell.SelStart = selectionStart + 1
            End If
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
            If Not e.Shift Then
                If selectionStart > 0 AndAlso Not e.Control Then

                    grid.ActiveCell.SelStart = selectionStart - 1
                End If
                grid.ActiveCell.SelLength = 0
            Else
                If selectionStart > 0 Then
                    If Not e.Control Then
                        grid.ActiveCell.SelStart -= 1
                        grid.ActiveCell.SelLength += 1
                    End If
                End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
```

While this is close some cases don't work properly. Is there a better or standard way?

Comment: "While this is close some things don't work properly" - what "things" are these and what does "properly" mean in this context? Is that they don't work at all or produce some undesirable behaviour?

Comment: @ChrisF I should have said some cases do not work properly. For example shift + arrow keys does not work the same as windows shift+arrow keys when selecting text.

Comment: Add that (and any other errors) to the question - you might get some answers.

Comment: @codemonkeyliketab Try to be more specific than 'does not work the same'. Does it select two characters at once? The whole word? Does shift+left also move the start location? Describe the behavior differences in detail.